# Adding days to date column and result in new column?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, dateadd

I need to add 40 days to a column , which contains date in d-m-y format,
and insert result into new column . eg

```
 $querydate="UPDATE services SET paymentdue_date=payment_date+30 DAY WHERE my condition ";
```

and i tried

```
 $querydate="SELECT up_id=".$up_id.",DATE_ADD(payment_date,INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS paymentdue_date FROM     up_services";
```

Column structure for payment_date and paymentdue_date is varchar10 utf8_unicode_ci
any suggestions?

Comment: Did you set your `payment_date` and `paymentdue_date` to `varchar(11)` ? Try `DATETIME`

Comment: its varchar 10 now , nd work for current date

Comment: so what's the error reporting message?

Comment: nothing, no erros, query runns successfully but o rows effected

Comment: No erros , query runns suucessfully but 0rows effected.....

if i try to run query for same column= date, it runs and save current date to column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried running this query and it worked for me , updated my column with new :)

```
 $querydate="UPDATE up_services SET paymentdue_date=DATE_ADD(payment_date,INTERVAL 30 DAY) WHERE my condition ";
```

Answer (score 1):

correct query will be

```
$querydate="SELECT up_id,DATE_ADD(payment_date,INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS paymentdue_date FROM up_services where up_id='$up_id'";
```

you can't add compare in select like `up_id=".$up_id."` use where instead

if you want update query you can follow  **@saharsh shah** answer

Comment: I tried this 

$querydate="SELECT up_id,DATE_ADD(payment_date,INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS paymentdue_date FROM up_services where up_id='$up_id'";

@RakeshSharma

Comment: what you mean by not working echo your query run through phpmyadmin

Comment: SELECT up_id,DATE_ADD(payment_date,INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS paymentdue_date FROM up_services where up_id=147

run this , nd query successfull but didnt add any value in my paymentdue_date column

Comment: if you want use update then use @saharsh shah answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE services 
SET paymentdue_date = DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(payment_date, '%e-%c-%y'), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
WHERE my condition
```

Comment: I tried this 


$querydate="UPDATE up_services SET paymentdue_date=DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(payment_date, '%e-%c-%y'), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
WHERE up_id=".$up_id."";


nd dint work